# out of memory exception during fast scrolling of listview

Tags: android

I am using listview to display facebook profile picture,name,message,postedpicture.

I used scrollviewListener to load the next page data.But when I scrolled fastly,without waiting to load the data completely I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.bitmap size exceeds VM budget.

I am getting this error at my ImageLoader class where the bitmap is returned.Did I need to change anything to deallocate memory.

The most important is I am calling another webservice when listview scroll reaches the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) of Android Documentation site.

They dedicate a few pages to this exact problem : `java.lang.OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.`

Comment: You got some on the links, even some github repo to clone to get started. No one can do that for you.